# Difficulty running jupyter notebook on Python2

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-2.x

I have both Python 2 (`2.7.14`) and Python 3 (`3.6.4`) installed on my computer
(`Linux rajarshi-x550cc 4.15.10-300.fc27.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 15 17:13:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`)

I have also installed Jupyter Notebook. When I run a new kernel on Jupyter Notebook, whether I choose to run the Python-2 kernel or the Python-3 kernel, only the Python-3 Kernel is run. I have checked this with `print(sys.version)`.

I got several nice answers here on Stackoverflow, but none of them worked for me. I created a JSON file in the Jupyter library in **/usr/share/jupyter/kernels/python2** with the following code:

```
{
 "display_name": "Python 2", 
 "language": "python", 
 "argv": [
  "python", 
  "-m", 
  "ipykernel_launcher", 
  "-f", 
  "{connection_file}"
 ]
}
```

but there was no observable difference.

I then uninstalled Jupyter from Python 3 as follows:
`python3 -m pip uninstall jupyter`
but Jupyter is still there, and it still recognizes only Python 3.

I am honestly at my wit's end. Should I simply remove Python 3 altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would completely uninstall python and go ahead as follows:

1. Install anaconda with pythn 3.6
2. Create a virtual environment with python 2.7

   `conda create -n python27 python=2.7 anaconda`
3. If I want jupyter notebook with python 3.6, I would just run `jupyter notebook`
4. For jupyter notebook with python 2.7 i will `activate python27` and then `jupyter notebook`. This will lauch notebook with python 2.7

Comment: I tried this. However, it did not work.
The virtual environment was created like a charm, but when I used `source activate python=2.7` and ran the Notebook application, it still registered 3.6 as the output of `print(sys.version)`.

Comment: To activate you should use `python27` and not `python=2.7`. Does your prompt change when you activate the environment?

Comment: The conda package manager produced a line at the output which said that I had to use python=2.7; I tried both anyway, neither worked.  
In any case, the problem has been solved using ipykernel. (see answer by *ScottMcC* above).  
Nevertheless, thank you Mr. Joshi.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ipykernel` to register different versions of python in the same notebook environment.

See the following documentation for more information
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-python-2-and-3